# Manually set route using ip route

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have two network interfaces, wlp3s0 and eno1.

wlp3s0 connects to the Internet, while eno1 connects to an internal network.

I have been able to set up the network by using 'ip route' to a partially working status:

```
default via 193.150.115.1 dev wlp3s0 
10.1.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.46 
193.150.115.0/22 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 193.150.115.133
```

However, this does not allow me to connect to some other servers on the internal network, for example, one with the IP address of 10.1.8.22.

What do I need to do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a newbie question !

I suggest you to type  on your system:

ip route get 10.1.8.22

By that command, you get the route set INTO your system to reach 10.1.8.22.
The result may not be compliant with your problem description. Currently, to reach 10.1.8.22, you may go to Internet, not internal network.

I suggest you to add a route:

ip route add 10.1.8.0/24 dev eno1

Regards